# Fast way to include a Web User Control in a Web Form on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I know this way on Visual Studio 2008 :

write "somethings" when I'll to include the resource, click on `Design`, drag and drop the `Web User Control` and return to the `Source`.

I'd like to know if I can do it without use the `Design` area, maybe some buttons like CTRL and than drag and drop directly on the `Source` area.

Is it possible? Or do you know other ways? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can/must compile your web user control separately, then it is possible to add it to your toolbox via Choose Items... and locating the dll.

Then you can drag the control directly to source like you would any other control.

Comment: right click in any area where you want to add your control in toolbox.

Comment: ? But I need to add my own Web user Control page (like Events.ascx for example...). And this is not so faster than the Design method :)

Comment: it is once you have made your user control and added it to the toolbox, then all you do is drag it to source. But I agree there is some ground work to do first.